# Unable to extend a partition in gparted

Tags: partition, gparted

In my sdb drive I have 76 Gb of unallocated space. I would like to extend the partition sdb3. However gparted hangs if a try to extend this partition. Anyone knows why?[image]

Comment: Debugging hung programs is difficult, to have any hope of finding an answer please provide as much information as possible.  At exactly what point does gparted "hang"?  Eg: is this when you click apply?  Are you able to expand the "details" section on the progress window that gparted opens while writing to disk?  If so, what what operation is it trying to perform when it gets stuck.  Please [edit] your question to add as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the content of this partition to anther hard drive. Then I deleted the sd3 partition and finally I create a new partition with the full size of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You should Unmount/Unlock the mounted partition (select the partition, right clic) , then you will be able to extend the `/dev/sdb3`